# catkin_make's option for optimization

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used Eigen library for my program and found that matrix calculation is very slow(Just "for loop" is faster !!).

I think that optimization is not carried out when making the program.
How can I optimize the program ?
**Any good catkin option for optimization ?**

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172950/catkin_make%27s-option-for-optimization/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_make is just a wrapper around CMake, so you can use the standard CMake variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to enable various build options.

For a release configuration with opmizations and no debugging symbols, you can use the `Release` build type:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

For a release with debug configuration, with optimizations and debug symbols, you can use the `RelWithDebInfo` build type:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
```

CMake's [useful variables](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Compilers_and_Tools) page gives more information about build types.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on 2015-05-04**:
Could you provide an example of compiling rviz without any optimizations?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-05-04**:
`catkin_make -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O0` will force it to not have any optimizations, but it should be sufficient to do `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` to prevent CMake from introducing optimization flags.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-05-04**:
See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5765916/671658

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After entering "catkin_make -D" and hitting tab you should also get completion when using a bash shell. So you don't have to remember the exact names.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3